# How to make vector of GraphicsPath?

Tags: c++, vector, gdi+, graphicspath

I want to make a `std::vector` of `Gdiplus::GraphicsPath` like so:

```
std::vector<Gdiplus::GraphicsPath> test;
```

but when I try to add an item e.g.

```
test.emplace_back(rndRectPathData.Points, rndRectPathData.Types, rndRectPathData.Count);
```

I get errors:

```
Error   C2672   'std::construct_at': no matching overloaded function found  

Error   C2783   '_Ty *std::construct_at(_Ty *const ,_Types &&...) noexcept(<expr>)': could not deduce template argument for '<unnamed-symbol>'

Error   C2248   'Gdiplus::GraphicsPath::GraphicsPath': cannot access protected member declared in class 'Gdiplus::GraphicsPath'
```

Is it not possible?  Why?

Comment: I think it's It's tripping over the copy constructor because the copy constructor is `protected`. `vector` does a lot of copying and assigning and if it can't copy and assign, game over. The class is not suitable for storage in a `vector`. Perhaps a simple wrapper class that will keep the allocator happy or a custom allocator?

Comment: If all else fails, take a performance hit and use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Gdiplus::GraphicsPath>>` to get you back on a working path and figure out how to properly copy (move if you can) `GraphicsPath`s later.